# How can I implement something similar to 'SKIP LOCKED' in MySQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql, multithreading

I am currently using 'for update' to read lock a record while one thread reads a row from the table. However when another thread reads the table, it's giving me the same record back after the first threads completed its transaction and releases the lock on its record.

Is there any way to skip locked records while reading in MySQL 5.7?

Answer (score 0):

The functionality of `SKIP LOCKED` is not supported in MySQL 5.7. But it is in MySQL 8.0:

https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-1-using-skip-locked-and-nowait-to-handle-hot-rows/

If you need some software function, then you should upgrade to the software that does support it.